# converting very long string into numeric

Tags: string, stata, numeric, panel-data

I have a person identification number variable in a panel dataset that is of string type with 19 characters (`str19`). Whenever I convert it into numeric using the `destring` command I lose precision because it is converted into either `double` (max 16 characters) or `float`, meaning that the ID numbers no longer identify respondents uniquely. I need it to be numeric in order to treat the data as panel (`xt` commands). What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The best way forward I can think of is to use `egen`'s `group()` function to create identifiers. You don't provide a data or code example, but this illustrates the point.

```
. clear 

. set obs 1 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen strid = "1234567890123456789"

. egen numid = group(strid), label 

. list 

     +-------------------------------------------+
     |               strid                 numid |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1234567890123456789   1234567890123456789 |
     +-------------------------------------------+

. list, nolabel 

     +-----------------------------+
     |               strid   numid |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 1234567890123456789       1 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

Note that this is documented: [see this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/).

Comment: thanks @Nick it worked! I used the following code:                                           `egen long panelid = group(ind)`                                                                           where ind is my old string identification variable and panelid is the new numeric one